# Comparing automatically filled in dates with manual entered ones

Tags: excel, time

I currently have some data I imported from CSV into excel. In this file I have some timestamps, that I need to compare to a list of other timestamps. To create the list of other timestamps, I used the drag feature, i.e. I entered `00:00` and `00:15` into the first two rows, and dragged down till `23:45`.

However, when I am comparing timestamps from this list with the ones from the CSV file, I get `FALSE` even for timestamps that are the same. For example, if I compare `0:30` from the drag down list, with `0:30` from the CSV I get `FALSE`.

Looking at the way the formula is evaluated, I can see that the timestamp from the CSV is represented as `0.0208333333333333` whereas the one that was created using dragging is represented as `0.0208333333333299`. So Excel is creating some kind of rounding error when dragging timestamps. When I use different timestamps to start (e.g. `0:15` and `0:30`) I get incorrect results for other comparisons.

What is the correct way to autocomplete timestamps in excel without these kinds of rounding errors?

I am using Excel 2010, Version 14.0.7145.5000 (64 Bit).

**EDIT**

Ok, I tried it again, and after some re-entering and re-dragging it suddenly worked. However I cannot really tell, what to do to make it work correctly.

Comment: You could get an equal result for both if you use a helper column with =FLOOR(A1,1/86400). This should ensure the time is rounded down to the nearest second

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without going to deep into excel I'd suggest using a "safer" comparison like:
=IF(ABS(D3-E3)<0.00001, TRUE, FALSE)
Notice that you can adjust the precision to the level you want/need.

If you, on the other hand, prefer to adjust your excel book. I'd try to check how to ensure the data type of both columns is the same, in this case, TIME. I know you can do that in Excel 2013, but I am not sure for Excel 2010. But if you choose this option you should consider also that if the csv was generated by another excel document then that document may not have the right datatype set.

Comment: The data type is the same on both columns. I already tried manually setting it, but that didn't really solve the problem...

The ABS() part probably would do the trick.

Comment: Ok, just tried it, and the ABS() part also works fine on array functions (which is where I am using the comparison).